# php: try-catch not catching all exceptions

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to do the following:

```
try {
    // just an example
    $time      = 'wrong datatype';
    $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return false;
}
// database activity here
```

In short: I initialize some variables to be put in the database. If the initialization fails for whatever reason - e.g. because $time is not the expected format - I want the method to return false and not input wrong data into the database.

However, errors like this are not caught by the 'catch'-statement, but by the global error handler. 
And then the script continues.

Is there a way around this? I just thought it would be cleaner to do it like this instead of manually typechecking every variable, which seems ineffective considering that in 99% of all cases nothing bad happens.

Comment: That's because exceptions are not universally implemented in PHP.  They are a PHP5 addition, and very few of the built-in functions will throw them. Instead, you will need to verify the return values of most functions.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### Solution #1

Use [ErrorException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) to turn errors into exceptions to handle:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

### Solution #2

```
try {
    // just an example
    $time      = 'wrong datatype';
    if (false === $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time)) {
        throw new Exception('date error');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: A couple notes: 1) If it's not desired to universally raise exceptions in place of errors throughout the application, this can be enabled where desired and regular error handling can be restored with [`restore_error_handler()`](http://php.net/restore_error_handler). 2) I expect #2 to still throw a warning. Same concept applies: the error reporting level could be changed with [`error_reporting()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and changed back afterward.

Comment: The warning MUST BE threw anyway. They are information that you must save it somewhere. If you do not want to see it, just turn off `error_display`

Comment: Solution #2 is how Js does it... it's good if you know what you're doing

Comment: Follow up question: Is it good idea to use solution #1 in your MVC applications? I feel using it globally defeats the purpose of Exceptions while repeatedly using `restore_error_handler()` feels very hackish.

Comment: Only on debug mode @VarunAgrawal, during the developement. I'd not relay on a global php setting to handle correctly how your application will in fact run in the end.

Comment: @Federkun Thanks. That's actually quite a strong argument. I will stay away from these in future

Comment: For PHP 7 must catch \Throwable separately
See the other answer.

Answer (score 145):

```
try {
  // call a success/error/progress handler
} catch (\Throwable $e) { // For PHP 7
  // handle $e
} catch (\Exception $e) { // For PHP 5
  // handle $e
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is heavily under-documented, you can barely notice it, if you're lucky and come to both https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.error.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php links ... because the one that should contain this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php - *does not even contain word Throwable* (in doc part).

Comment: In what circumstances would this go to the later catch block? When the Exception class implements the Throwable interface, wouldn't this always be catched in the first catch block?

Comment: @Gemmu [When the script runs with PHP 5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php#124604) where `Throwable` does not exist.

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to use `catch(Throwable $e)` to catch all exceptions and errors like so:

```php
catch ( Throwable $e){
    $msg = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The shorter that I have found:

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ){
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
});
```

Makes all errors becoming instance of catchable `ErrorException`

Answer (score 8):

It's also possible to define multiple types for the `$e` parameter in catch:

```php
try {
    // just an example
    $time      = 'wrong datatype';
    $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
} catch (Exception|TypeError $e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note to readers: this syntax works only for PHP 7.1 and later. *"As of PHP 7.1.0, a catch block may specify multiple exceptions using the pipe (|) character. This is useful for when different exceptions from different class hierarchies are handled the same."*