# symfony 2.1 + try / catch block isn't working in a console command

Tags: php, symfony, try-catch, console-application, symfony-2.1

I am using a console command that is executed via cron. I want to catch every exception and writing it in a log but my catch is not working at all.

The part of the code that is throwing the error is when calling "ejecutar" (this is on purpose) that error is printed in console but the code after catch dont print anything in the log

```
<?php
namespace daci\contratosBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleExceptionEvent;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

//logger
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;

class SeguimientosRemainderEmailCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    //Administrador
    protected $emailAdmin       = "....@.....sv";
    protected $clasePhp         = "SeguimientosRemainderEmailCommand.php";
    protected $nombreProceso    = "SeguimientosRemainderEmail";
    protected $comando          = "dacicontratosBundle:seguimientos_remainder_email";
    protected $descripcion      = "Recordatorio semanal para seguimiento de contratos";
    protected $tiempoEjecucion  = "Lun | 8:00am";
    protected $mensaje          = "";
    protected $asunto           = "ITIGES - Servicio de Notificaciones - ";

    protected $logger;
    protected $text         = "";
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName($this->comando)
             ->setDescription($this->descripcion)
             ->addArgument('my_argument', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Argument description');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {


        try{
            //logger
            $this->logger = $this->getContainer()->get('logger');
            $this->text = strtoupper('---- INICIO SEGUIMIENTOS REMAINDER EMAIL -----');
            $this->logger->info($this->text);

            $this->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
            $this->getContainer()->set('request', new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request(), 'request');

            ejecutar(); //HERE IS WHERE IT FAILS


            $this->mensaje = "<strong>Éxito</strong>" ."<br/>";
            $this->mensaje = $this->mensaje . "<strong>Clase php:</strong>              ".$this->clasePhp."<br/>";
            $this->mensaje = $this->mensaje . "<strong>Comando ejecutado:</strong>      ".$this->comando."<br/>";
            $this->mensaje = $this->mensaje . "<strong>Descripción:</strong>            ".$this->descripcion."<br/>";
            $this->mensaje = $this->mensaje . "<strong>Ejecución programada:</strong>   ".$this->tiempoEjecucion."<br/>";
            $datetime = new \DateTime();
            $this->mensaje = $this->mensaje . "<strong>Hora de ejecución:</strong>      ".$datetime->format('Y\-m\-d\ h:i:s');

            $this->enviarMailAdmin($this->comando, $this->mensaje);


        }catch (\Exception $re) {
            $this->logger->error($re->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This is the error I'm trying to catch but I would like to catch any kind of error/exception

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function daci\contratosBundle\Command\ejecutar()
in C:\Dropbox\Apache Xampp\evaluacion_daci\src\daci\contratosBundle\Command\Segu
imientosRemainderEmailCommand.php on line 82
```

any idea whats going on?

Comment: Are you sure that logging is turned on? Are you tailing the log file and seeing anything echoed to the log file?

Comment: Hi! Log is working perfectly

Comment: If you var_dump or echo the exception message, will it print in your output?

Comment: Nope! The only thing that is showing me its the Error in console command.

Comment: Echo and var_dump is working inside try but not in catch

Comment: @RodolVelasco Did you find the cause? I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: Anyway, I found the cause (Solution #1) in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15461666/1903743

Answer (score 0):

From basics of PHP:
`try{} catch(){}` block can catch errors thrown only as `Exception`.

You didn't paste here error log (please do it), but I think it's a fatal error, or kind of.

Remember, those errors are not catchable. So even inside try-catch they will broke script.

Comment: I would like to catch every kind of error and write it on a log. I edited the question in order you can see what I trying to catch