# Php: Catch all the errors entire the program

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

I want to catch all the errors in my code.
I know that we can use the [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function to set a exception handler function for doing it, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461611/php-try-catch-not-catching-all-exceptions).
But, if I use this method previous handler will be disabled, and I do not want something like that. Do you have any idea?

beforehand appreciate any help

Comment: Does this help: _It is important to remember that the standard PHP error handler is completely bypassed for the error types specified by error_types unless the callback function returns FALSE._ [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I looking for a way to catch the exceptions after or before executing previously defined exception handler. Can I write: `function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    //do something
    restore_error_handler();
    try{throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);}
    catch(Exception $e){}
    finally{set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");}
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");` ?

Comment: and, according to the manual: **If the function returns FALSE then the normal error handler continues.** So can I write this for that? : 
`function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) { try{//do something}catch(Exception $ex){}finally{return false;}
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");`

Comment: I would give it a try and see what happens